# Comparing two lists Recursively in LISP

Tags: common-lisp

I am currently trying to create a function which compares the contents of two lists sorted by ascendancy and creates one list that is also sorted by ascendancy.

For example (4 6 8 9 10) (1 2 5 7 9) would become (1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 10)

As we are working with recursion I expect that this must be done recursively. My knowledge of LISP is limited and I am struggling with this greatly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try to work out the base cases - For what inputs is the output trivial to produce (hint: the output might just be one of the inputs). Once you've dealt with base cases, think about what work you will perform before you make a recursive call.

Comment: Your question lacks information about the algorithm you want to implement and what you have tried so far. What you describe is independent of Lisp and can be written in many programming languages.

Comment: At the moment I am trying to create a third list which is the 1st and 2nd lists appended to one another. And then performing an insertion sort upon it. But I struggle with creating the list itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counter variable in LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705229/counter-variable-in-lisp)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement this yourself.  Common Lisp has the function [**merge**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_merge.htm):

```
CL-USER> (merge 'list '(4 6 8 9 10) '(1 2 5 7 9) '<)
(1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is called a *merge*.

You build a new list by always looking at the first element of each list and taking the lower one.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it recursively then you can

```
(defun merge1 (ls1 ls2)
  (cond ((null ls1) ls2)
        ((null ls2) ls1)
        ((< (car ls1) (car ls2))
         (cons (car ls1)
               (merge1 (cdr ls1) ls2)))
        (t (cons (car ls2)
                 (merge1 ls1 (cdr ls2))))))
```